# Can't mass-assign protected attributes in multistep form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm doing something I thought would be quite simple that's ended up being very complicated. I've followed this [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms) to create a multistep form. Now I'm trying to nest a form in `Order` views to create a parent `Customer` if one doesn't already exist inside of it (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935153/rails-3-2-create-parent-model-from-child-view) question).

Basically, I want a customer to be created to own an order if they don't already exist. Am I going about this the wrong way?

At present, I get

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: customer_attributes

when I have Orders `belongs_to :customers`. But that seems most logical to me? I've put the code below.

Customer Model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address_1, :address_2, :email, :name, :phone, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Order Model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :customer_id, :format, :message, :phone, :quantity

  belongs_to :customer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer
  attr_writer :current_step

...
```

Relevant Order controller methods:

```
  # GET /orders/new
  # GET /orders/new.json
  def new
    session[:order_params] ||= {}
    @order = Order.new(session[:order_params])
    @order.build_customer(session[:order_params])
    @order.current_step = session[:order_step]
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    session[:order_params].deep_merge!(params[:order]) if params[:order]
    @order = Order.new(session[:order_params])
    @order.current_step = session[:order_step]
    if params[:back_button]
      @order.previous_step
    elsif @order.last_step?
      @order.save
    else
      @order.next_step
    end
    session[:order_step] = @order.current_step

    if @order.new_record?
      render 'new'
    else
      session[:order_step] = session[:order_params] = nil
      flash[:notice] = "Order saved."
      redirect_to @order
    end
  end
```

views/orders/new

```
%h1 New order

= form_for(@order) do |f|
  - if @order.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error")
        prohibited this order from being saved:
      %ul
        - @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  = render "#{@order.current_step}_step", :f => f 
  = f.submit "Continue"
  = f.submit "Back", :name => "back_button" unless @order.first_step?
```

The partial view in which I'm trying to nest the form:

```
.field
  = f.label :quantity    
  = f.text_field :quantity

%h3
  Customer details

=f.fields_for :customer do |builder|
  =builder.label :name
  =builder.text_field :name

  =builder.label :email
  =builder.text_field :email
```

Hopefully that's everything. I've done nested forms before, but never in combination with a multistep form. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441819/cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes-tags-attributes

Comment: Yes, sorry - I thought it was something to do with the multistep form. It's not, so I've accepted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need both:

```
attr_accessible :customer_attributes, :customer_id, :format, :message, :phone, :quantity
accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer
```

`attr_accessible` tells Rails those attributes area allowed.

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` tells rails to delegate attributes to an other class.