# Create parent model from child controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, nested-forms

I'm working on on a web app that takes in information about companies.  Information can be taken for a `PreferredOffering` (of stock) or an `Incorporation`.  So in other words, when I create a new entry to either one of those models, a new company is formed.

It works out that my database is cleaner if `PreferredOffering` and `Incorporation` are children of `Company`, even though I'm trying to go through the `preferred_offerings_controller` or the`incorporations_controller` to create a new `Company`.  Here lies my question; I'm trying to figure out how to configure my view and controllers to create a parent model from a child controller. I've done some research and have seen two [other S/O posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935153/rails-3-2-create-parent-model-from-child-view) on how to accomplish this with Rails 3, however it would seem that the addition of strong params adds another layer of complexity to the endeavor.

### So I have my models set up like this

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :incorporation, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :preferred_offerings, dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :preferred_offerings, allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :incorporation, allow_destroy: true
end
```

.

```
class Incorporation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

.

```
class PreferredOffering < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
end
```

### The controller and view are what I'm iffy on.

Let's just take a look at the incorporation view/controller.  **If I were to configure it so that `Incorporation has_one :company`,** I would set it up as follows:

```
class IncorporationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @user=current_user
    @incorporation = @user.incorporations.build
    @company = @incorporation.build_company
  end

  def create
    @incorporation =   current_user.incorporations.build(incorporation_params)
  end

  private

  def incorporation_params
    params.require(:incorporation).permit(:title, :trademark_search, :user_id, :employee_stock_options, :submit, :_destroy,
                                                    company_attributes: [:id, :name, :employee_stock_options, :options_pool, :state_corp, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :issued_common_stock, :outstanding_common_stock, :fiscal_year_end_month, :fiscal_year_end_day, :user_id, :_destroy]
                                         )
    end

end
```

And the view would be:

```
<%= simple_form_for @incorporation, html: {id:"incorporationform"}, remote: false, update: { success: "response", failure: "error"} do |f| %>
    (incorporation-specific fields)
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :company do |company| %>
        (Company-specific fields)
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

### So my question is:

How do I need to modify my controller and view to create a `Company` from the `incorporations_controller` **IF** `Company has_one :incorporation`

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it isn't the "Rails Way", there is nothing really wrong with having `@company` being the parent in your form, even though it is in the `incorporations#new` action. Your view would change to this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @company, html: {id:"companyform"}, remote: false, update: { success: "response", failure: "error"} do |f| %>
  (company-specific fields)
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :incorporation do |incorporation| %>
    (incorporation-specific fields)
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And your strong params would change so that `Company` is the parent and `Incorporation` is the child.

Another option would be to simply go through the `Company` controller. You could create two new actions: `new_preferred_offering` and `new_incorporation`. You would then create the objects in those actions. Or you could pass in some kind of `:type` param so that the normal `new` action renders one of two forms based on which one you want.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the response!  I implemented the first method that you suggested and am getting the error `uninitialized constant CompaniesController`.  Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Comment: That means you haven't created a `CompaniesController` (that, or it's misspelled or in the wrong file). Create it just like the `IncorporationsController` and you should be fine.

Comment: I actually haven't created a CompaniesController.  I was hoping to do this all with the IncorporationsController.  I'm actually trying to resolve the error by specifying the controller with `url_for`.  Is that kosher?

Comment: Sure, you can direct the form to a different controller. Now, I've never used Simple Form, so how that is done, I don't know.

Comment: Using it with simple form seems pretty straightforward `url: url_for(action: 'create', controller: 'incorporations')`.  I'm now running into an `unknown attribute error` for all of the fields under company.  Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Make sure that the fields are in your migration(s), that the migrations have been run, and that they are spelled correctly in your form. Beyond that, I can't really help you there.

Comment: Turns out that I needed to change the strong params `incorporation_params` to `company_params` in order to get the attributes to take.